# Picard's theorem: Unique solution on rectangle implies unique solution on vertical strip?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I refer to the following version of Picard's theorem,

> Picard's theorem (PT):
>
> The IVP $y'(x) = f(x, y(x)), y(a) = b$ has a unique solution on the rectangle $R = \{ (x,y) : |x-a|\leq h, |y-b| \leq k\}$ provided,
>
> - $f$ is continuous on $R$ with bound $M$ satisfying $Mh \leq k$
> - $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $R$ in $y$.

My question is this:

Assuming PT applies to the IVP, is it then automatically true that the IVP has a unique solution on the strip $[a-h, a+h] \times \mathbb{R}$? That is, does every solution to the IVP lie in $R$ even if $f$ is not Lipschitz in $y$ outside above or below $R$?

Comment: The first condition gives $|y(x)-b|<M|x-a|$ for any solution, so how do you think the solution could leave $R$?

Comment: I agree. It just seemed strange to me and I wanted to check that I wasn't insane. I thought "Well, why bother with the rectangle in the first place then". But now I realise that the height of the rectangle and the bound of the function determine the range of values $h$. Many thanks!